# Adding double gang switch for two different lights?

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

I have power coming into a light fixture and down to the switch. I want to add a double gang to put in a second switch that would turn an outlet on/off in the bedroom. What is the proper way to take the power coming into the first switch and run it to the new switch for the outlets?

Comment: Same as before https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/88198/is-this-switch-a-three-way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this switch a three-way?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/88198/is-this-switch-a-three-way)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to pig tail with wire nuts inside the double gang box. You will be pig-tailing one hot one and one ground to each switch. Your neutral does not get tied in with the switch. Just wire nut all the neutrals together

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know if anything would be different since the power was coming from the fixture.

Comment: This works if the existing switch is relatively new so that there is neutral in the switch box. But traditionally a switch loop would **not** have a neutral - meaning just hot (bypassing the fixture), switched hot (going to the fixture) and ground. If you have neutral then you connect the neutrals (old unused from fixture + new fixture - not connecting to switches unless they are smart/timer/etc.) and everything is great. But if you don't have neutral then this can't be done without running a neutral wire from the fixture to the switch box.